# Too much recursion error due to bounds.extend method

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create bound and zoom to the my markers. But i have the error i mentioned at line:

```
bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
```

When i set the length of my markers.length in for loop then it gives `Too much recursion error`
I have all the markers displayed but they are not zoomed and bounded and i also have the error which i just mentioned.

My code to do this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        #map-canvas {
            width: 1350px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            //var markers = new Array();
            var markers = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: './Content/TextFile/LongLat.txt',
                //filereader\filereader\Content\TextFile\LongLat.txt
                //  url: './distinctGimeiNo.txt',
                dataType: 'text',
            }).success(function (data) {
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                var marker;
                var s2 = data.replace(/^.*$/, " ").replace(/\r\n/g, " ");
                var array = s2.split(/[ ]+/g);
                var test = [].concat.apply([], array.map(function (array) { return array.split(/\s+/); }))

                var col1 = [];
                var col2 = [];
                var col3 = [];
                var j = 0;
                // var currentLocation =
                var mapOptions =
                    {
                        zoom: 2,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(73, 23),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                for (var i = 0; i <= test.length - 3; i = i + 3) {
                    col1[j] = test[i];
                    col2[j] = test[i + 1];
                    col3[j] = test[i + 2];
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(col3[j], col2[j]);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                       {
                           position: myLatlng,
                           map: map,
                           title: 'Hello World! ' + col1[j]
                       });
                    markers.push(marker);
                    console.log("test2");
                    j++;
                }
                function AutoCenter() {
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
                    }
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
                AutoCenter();
            })
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        console.log("Check finished2");
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please let me know the solution of the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Your first set of coordinates is not valid.  When you put invalid coordinates into a google.map.LatLngBounds, the result is not usable for configuring the map (it generates the error you report `too much recursion`).

The first row of your data (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160608/how-to-replace-space-with)) doesn't contain numbers.

If I skip the first entry, it works for me:

```
    for (var i = 3; i <= test.length - 3; i = i + 3) {
        col1[j] = test[i];
        col2[j] = test[i + 1];
        col3[j] = test[i + 2];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(col3[j], col2[j]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World! ' + col1[j]
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        console.log("test2"+marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
        j++;
    }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4hkscug/1/)

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  //var markers = new Array();
  var markers = [];
  /*    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: './Content/TextFile/LongLat.txt',
          //filereader\filereader\Content\TextFile\LongLat.txt
          //  url: './distinctGimeiNo.txt',
          dataType: 'text',
      }).success(function (data) {
  */
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker;
  /*        var s2 = data.replace(/^.*$/, " ").replace(/\r\n/g, " ");
          var array = s2.split(/[ ]+/g);
          var test = [].concat.apply([], array.map(function (array) {
              return array.split(/\s+/);
          }))
  */
  // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160608/how-to-replace-space-with
  var rows = ["ID LONGITUDE LATITUDE", "0 77.139305 28.795975", "2 77.308929 28.486877", "4 73.820680 18.464110"];
  var test = [].concat.apply([], rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.split(' ');
  }))

  var col1 = [];
  var col2 = [];
  var col3 = [];
  var j = 0;
  // var currentLocation =
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(73, 23),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  for (var i = 3; i <= test.length - 3; i = i + 3) {
    col1[j] = test[i];
    col2[j] = test[i + 1];
    col3[j] = test[i + 2];
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(col3[j], col2[j]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World! ' + col1[j]
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    console.log("test2:" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
    j++;
  }

  function AutoCenter() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
  AutoCenter();
  //    })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
console.log("Check finished2");
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are out of bounds... replace `<=` by `<` in the for loop...

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
```

Check this [fiddle maps example](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/22qte/) to guide you... ;)

Searching a bit, I found some info, maybe your case:

> `LatLngBounds()` does not take two arbitrary points as parameters, but SW and NE points use the `.extend()` method on an **empty bounds object**

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(myPlace);
bounds.extend(Item_1);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: I mean something liek this : http://i.imgur.com/xsePfSq.png  It even dont load map now.

Comment: Actually i was trying to bound the markers to  zoom the area to fit all marks in it. If u see my code i do something like this : map.fitBounds(bounds); The one u have given i have already done that. And when i do that it gives too much recursion error.

Comment: But i dont have 1 item. There is a big file that i read. and i do bounds.extend(..) in for loop. I AM Not able to understand your Item_1 and bounds and myPlace . Please explain in detail.

Comment: there is a big file which contains Long lat and ID.. I am not allowed to write Marker statically for each. Is tehre any other solution ?

Comment: you have to use what I gave you, **CREATING `LatLngBounds()` object one time**, find the 2 farthest points in your file and use it to declare the bounds... check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120950/show-closest-result-of-a-geocoder-on-map/29125599#29125599 and modify it to find the points.